# What is being done in this bit shifting operation?

Tags: c++, bit-manipulation

```
(INBuffer[3] << 8) + INBuffer[2]
```

Is this essentially moving the bit in INBuffer[3] into INBuffer[2] or [3] being zero'ed out then added to [2]?

Comment: What language is this code in?

Comment: C++ but I'm translating to C#

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is a simple way to make a 16 bit value from two 8 bit values.

```
INBuffer[3] = 0b01001011;
INBuffer[2] = 0b00001001;

INBuffer[3]<<8 // 0b0100101100000000;
(INBuffer[3]<<8) + INBuffer[2] // 0b0100101100001001
```

Usually this is represented as

```
(INBuffer[3]<<8) | INBuffer[2];
```

Comment: Correct. This code extracts a 16-bit value from memory stored in Hi-Low format (as opposed to low-high on Intel) regardless of memory alignment and platform endianess. This makes sense if you're decoding a file format or reading data from a different CPU.

Answer (score 6):

Depending on the language this most likely computes

```
InBuffer[3] * 256 + InBuffer[2]
```

or (which is most likely the same depending on the language) performes packing two bytes into one 16-bit word.